# Remove formatting for specific column RadGrid MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I am using a `WPF` Application, In that i am using a telerik gird and also i am using `MVVM` model to bind data in the grid. I have set the rows to gray color and readonly based on some values. Its working fine.

Now i have to remove the formatting for 3 specific columns (i.e) i have to make the background to white and readonly to false.

The row made gray using the below code,

//Code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}">
 <Style.Triggers>
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
 </DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
 </telerik:RadGridView.RowStyle>
```

Row made ReadOnly using the below code,

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView" IsReadOnlyBinding="{Binding IsActive}" />
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved like this,

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnlyBinding="{Binding IsActive}">
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Binding the value to each of the column made this work. For those columns which are editable just got rid of `IsActive`.